# when using a <cite> tag, is it semantically valid to include both an episode/chapter and the source work?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, citations

This isn't really a problem per se, but I was curious and I couldn't find anyone talking about it online.

When it comes to use of the cite tag, I understand it's meant to be only for the title of a work, but I wanted to ask if - for example - it's more correct to `<cite>Book Name Only</cite>` or `<cite>Chapter Name, Book Name</cite>`? or if there's another way to do it that would be better and why?

Specifically I want to quote a horror podcast named The Magnus Archives, this is what it currently looks like:

```
<p><cite>MAG004 - #0132806 (The Magnus Archives)</cite>, by Jonathan Sims.</p>
```

Should it just be `<cite>(The Magnus Archives)</cite>` ? I know I'm probably overthinking this, but I just want to know for the sake of it.

edit: i'm quoting text from an episode (pasted below).

Instead, my attention was fixed on a picture attached to the one small area of wall not covered by bookshelves. It was a painting of an eye. Very detailed, and at first I almost would have said almost photorealistic, but the more I looked at it, the more I saw the patterns and symmetries that formed into a single image, until I was so focused on them that I started to have difficulty seeing the eye itself.
      
    Written below it were three lines, in fine green calligraphy: “Grant us the sight that we may not know. Grant us the scent that we may not catch. Grant us the sound that we may not call.”

Comment: Please checkout [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: The format you choose depends on the level of specificity you need.  What are you discussing? The podcast itself or a specific episode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one title should be used per `<cite>` element.

The [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element) specification states (emphasis mine):

> **The [cite](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element) element [represents](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#represents) the title of a work** (e.g. a book, a paper, an essay, a poem, a score, a song, a script, a film, a TV show, a game, a sculpture, a painting, a theatre production, a play, an opera, a musical, an exhibition, a legal case report, a computer program, etc.).

Both a podcast series and a podcast episode could independently be considered standalone "works", but a `<cite>` element should be used to mark up the title of only one work at a time. So it would be incorrect to put two titles (the podcast title and the episode title) inside a singular `<cite>`.

```html
// incorrect usage because it contains two titles
<p><cite>MAG004 - #0132806 (The Magnus Archives)</cite>, by Jonathan Sims.</p>
```

Instead you could choose the episode title or the podcast title, or even both separately. (I would argue that "Page Turner" is the true title of the fourth episode, not MAG004, but that could be debated.)

```html
// correct
<p>MAG004 - #0132806 (<cite>The Magnus Archives</cite>), by Jonathan Sims.</p>

// also correct
<p>MAG004: <cite>Page Turner</cite> (The Magnus Archives), by Jonathan Sims.</p>

// also correct
<p>MAG004: <cite>Page Turner</cite> (<cite>The Magnus Archives</cite>), by Jonathan Sims.</p>
```

Note that the parentheses should not go inside the `<cite>` since they're not part of the title.